# How to train h2o automl models iteratively

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, automl

I was trying to train using `h2o.automl()`. But the training exited due to timeout. I know `max_runtime_secs` can be set to higher numbers. But it would be great if we can train for 1 hour, then save it somewhere. Again train it next day from where it was left in day 1.

How to do that ?

I have tried by setting `project_name` - but nothing is saved on exit. So if we turn off pc and restart, it is of no use.

I have used the following code for this :

```
library( h2o )

h2o.init( nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = '10240m' )

train = h2o.importFile( 'train.csv' )

automl_model = h2o.automl( y = 'outcome', training_frame = train, nfolds = 3, max_runtime_secs = 1800,

                           project_name = 'automl_aus_tennis' )
```

Link to train.csv : http://www.mediafire.com/file/qj7yiju15ncgnax/train.csv

Answer (score 4):

You can run `h2o.automl()` repeatedly with the same `project_name` and different seeds to build additional models and add them to the same `leaderboard`.  I do this all the time.

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/1867), which should go in soon, which allows you to specify algos not to run.  This allows you to tune which hyperparameter searches get executed on each `AutoML` run.

You'll need to keep the `h2o-3` instance running to achieve your aim since you can't currently persist the state of an `AutoML` run to disk and load it into a new `h2o-3` instance, or add models loaded from disk into a `leaderboard`.  Those would be useful feature requests.  :-)

Comment: Keeping the h2o-3 instance running is difficult. I will post this as a feature request in github. It would be highly helpful for complex models.

Also why different seed is required. If different one is used, automl will start from another starting model ?

Also how do we know what models are added in subsequent runs - using the leaderboard slot right ?

Comment: If you use the same seed for each run then the sequence of hyperparameter vectors will be the same for each hyperparameter search in the subsequent runs, so you'll get duplicate models between runs.

The timestamp for the `AutoML` run will be part of the `model_id` of each model, so it'll be easy to tell which models came from which runs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to continue running an H2O AutoML job if you shut down the H2O cluster (or machine) and restart the H2O cluster at a later date.  If you leave the H2O cluster running, you can add more models to your leaderboard by running `h2o.automl()` again with the same value for `project_name`.

If you need to shut down the H2O cluster between runs, then the best you can do is to set a different `seed` in the `h2o.automl()` function when you run it a second, third, fourth, etc. time because your random grid searches within the AutoML run will be different.  That way you're likely to get new models instead of models you've already trained in previous AutoML runs.